# Restkit nested objects mapping

Tags: ios, restkit

how can I map nested objects like

```
Category{
    "categoryID":1,
    "categoryName":blue,
    "parentCategory":{
          "categoryID":1,
          "categoryName":red,
     }
}
```

how can I map objects with parent-chid relationship in JSON response.
In here a category object has a parent category object.